# How to get absolute number of months ago in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

There a number of questions regarding this, but I couldn't find the exact answer.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2015-01-15');
$datetime2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%m months');
```

As today is 2015-05-11 this returns `3 months`. I would like it to always assume it's the *1st day of the month* for `$datetime1` so it should actually return `4 months`

I supposed I could use `str_replace()` or some other string function to lop off the day part of `$datetime1` but I'm assuming there is a more elegant method?

Thanks

Comment: what about `$date = strtotime('-1 month');`

Comment: @BookOfZeus, for which?  for datetime1 if the date provided was the actual 1st of the month, using -1 months would return 5 months.  For datetime2, that would return 2 months.

Comment: @Devon `echo date('Y-m-01', strtotime('last month'));` or sometihng like that

Comment: @BookOfZeus, for datetime2? The first of last month would be April 1st, so that would return 2 months instead of 4 months when the diff is applied from January 15th, that the OP is after.  If you're going to change `$datetime2`, you'd have to use the first of the next month, but that would still error out when the date actually is the first of the month.  Because then you'd be adding another month for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If '2015-01-15' is variable.  You could do:

```
$date = '2015-01-15';
$datetime1 = new DateTime( date('Y-m-01', strtotime($date)) );
```

Or use a substring function.

```
$date = '2015-01-15';
$datetime1 = new DateTime( substr($date, 0, 7).'-01' );
```

Substring would be faster but strtotime() can handle various formats.

Comment: Thanks. I like answer #1.

Comment: @user2029890, glad it helped you.  Please mark this as the correct answer if this resolved it for you.